# Java: Switch Statement Repeating/Defaulting Odd Behavior

Tags: java

This is part of a school assignment, so I know some of the code is a bit convoluted, but it's all required. I'm having an odd issue with my Switch statement, everything else works correctly though so I'm not worried about the rest of the code.

If I choose headphone 1, and enter volume 1, it works as expected. If I choose headphone 1 and enter volume 2, it asks the question twice and then works. If I choose headphone 1 and enter volume 3, it repeats three times. If I select headphone 2 and enter volume 1, it asks me twice and then goes to the default case. Odd behavior continues through the rest as well.

I'm guessing this is something obvious that I'm missing, but I've been troubleshooting for a while now and can't figure out what's going on. I'd appreciate any guidance or code corrections. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HeadPhone {

//Three constants to denote headphone volume
public static final int LOW = 1;
public static final int MEDIUM = 2;
public static final int HIGH = 3;

//Private variables 
private static int volume;
private boolean pluggedIn;
private String manufacturer;
private String headPhoneColor;

//This constructs the default headphone object
HeadPhone(){
   volume = MEDIUM;
   pluggedIn = false;
   manufacturer = "DEFAULT";
   headPhoneColor = "DEFAULT";
   }

   public void setVolume(int v){
   if(v < LOW){
       volume = LOW;
   }
   else if(v > HIGH){
       volume = HIGH;
   }
   else{
       volume = v;  
   }
}

public void setPluggedIn(boolean p){
   pluggedIn = p;
}

public void setManufacturer(String m){
   manufacturer = m;
}

public void setColor(String C){
   headPhoneColor = C;
}

public int getVolume(){
   return volume;
}

public boolean getPluggedIn(){
   return this.pluggedIn;
}

public String getManufacturer(){
   return this.manufacturer;
}

public String getColor(){
   return this.headPhoneColor;
}

public void changeVolume(int volume){
   setVolume(volume);
}

public String toString(){
   String temp = "Volume: " + volume + "\nPlugged In: " + pluggedIn +
           "\nManufacturer: " + manufacturer + "\nColor: " + headPhoneColor + "\n";
   return temp;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
   String volMessage = "What volume would you like to set? 1 for LOW, 2 for MEDIUM, or 3 for HIGH. ";          

   //Creates the object h1 and displays its statistics
   HeadPhone h1 = new HeadPhone();
   h1.setVolume(LOW);
   h1.setManufacturer("Logitech");
   h1.setColor("Black");
   h1.setPluggedIn(true);
   h1.changeVolume(MEDIUM);
   System.out.println("Headphone Set #1\n" + h1);

   //Creates the object h2 and displays its statistics
   HeadPhone h2 = new HeadPhone();
   h2.setVolume(LOW);
   h2.setManufacturer("Steel Series");
   h2.setColor("Silver");
   h2.setPluggedIn(true);
   h2.changeVolume(HIGH);
   System.out.println("Headphone Set #2\n" + h2);

   //Creates the object h3 and displays its statistics
   HeadPhone h3 = new HeadPhone();
   h3.setVolume(LOW);
   h3.setManufacturer("Panasonic");
   h3.setColor("Red");
   h3.setPluggedIn(true);
   h3.changeVolume(LOW);
   System.out.println("Headphone Set #3\n" + h3);

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   //This logic allows the user to either select to change the volume on their headphones or not
   System.out.print("\n\nWould you like to change the volume on your headphones? Y or N? ");
   String choice = input.nextLine();
   if (choice.equals("Y") || choice.equals("y")){
       System.out.print("\nWhich headphone set would you like to change the volume of? 1, 2, or 3? ");
       int hpSelect = input.nextInt();


       //This switch statement allows the user to change the volume of their selected headphone set
       switch(hpSelect){
            case 1:
                System.out.print(volMessage);
                int volSelect = input.nextInt();
                if (volSelect == 1){
                    h1.changeVolume(LOW);
                    System.out.println("\n" + h1);
                    break;
                }      

            case 2:
                System.out.print(volMessage);
                volSelect = input.nextInt();
                if (volSelect == 2){
                    h1.changeVolume(MEDIUM);
                    System.out.println("\n" + h2);
                    break;
                } 

            case 3:
                System.out.print(volMessage);
                volSelect = input.nextInt();
                if (volSelect == 3){
                    h1.changeVolume(HIGH);
                    System.out.println("\n" + h3);
                    break;
                }

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid entry.");
                break;



       }//End switch statement

       input.close();
   }//End if statement

   else{
        System.out.println("Okay! Enjoy your music!");
   }
```

Comment: Can you try put the break statement outside of the if statement?

Comment: I've moved the break statements to outside the if brackets. But now the println command in each if statement never executes.

Comment: School assignment... Jesus, wish my school taught Java .-.

Comment: `case` blocks do not flow automatically to the end of the switch as some expect.  Instead, execution flows right on through the next `case` label and into the next statement block as if the `case` label were not there at all.  You must use a `break` statement immediately before the next `case` label if you wish execution to flow to the end of the `switch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `break` is not at the right position.

Your `break` should always be at the very end of the `case`

Here is the corrected part of your code :

```
switch(hpSelect){
        case 1:
            System.out.print(volMessage);
            int volSelect = input.nextInt();
            if (volSelect == 1){
                h1.changeVolume(LOW);
                System.out.println("\n" + h1);   
            }; break;    

        case 2:
            System.out.print(volMessage);
            volSelect = input.nextInt();
            if (volSelect == 2){
                h1.changeVolume(MEDIUM);
                System.out.println("\n" + h2);
            }; break;

        case 3:
            System.out.print(volMessage);
            volSelect = input.nextInt();
            if (volSelect == 3){
                h1.changeVolume(HIGH);
                System.out.println("\n" + h3);
            }; break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid entry.");
            break;



   }//End switch statement
```

Here is an example of output

```
Which headphone set would you like to change the volume of? 1, 2, or 3? 1
What volume would you like to set? 1 for LOW, 2 for MEDIUM, or 3 for HIGH. 1

Volume: 1
Plugged In: true
Manufacturer: Logitech
Color: Black
```

Comment: Okay, I have corrected that, but now my System.out.println("\n" + h1); code doesn't execute, the program just ends.

Comment: @bnr32jason it works just fine. What inputs are you using?

Comment: In your original post I either missed the semicolon following each closing bracket or you forgot to type them. Either way, I added them and now everything works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: And why are there `;`s after the closing if bracket? They're no-ops and pointless...

Comment: @BenKnoble You can go and read about the conventions. Look at the example : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html

Comment: I did. And i didnt seen any semicolons at the end of if brackets. Any good compiler will optimize them away anyway.

Comment: @BenKnoble You can find the semicolon at the end of "statements" right before the "break". I agree with you but for the sake of clarity and for the conventions, I prefer this way of writing.

Comment: Ooh i see what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, your break is inside of the if loop.

For all of these, you should move the break after the if statement. So here's how it'd look for case 3:

```
    case 3:
        System.out.print(volMessage);
        volSelect = input.nextInt();
        if (volSelect == 3){
            h1.changeVolume(HIGH);
            System.out.println("\n" + h3);

        }
    break;
```

After you do this for default, case 1, and case 2, you'll be all set.

Comment: If is not a loop, its a control or branching structure, just fyi.